# How to get percentage of matching image in KNN algorithm for face recognition

Tags: python, face-recognition, knn

I am currently following this repo: https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/face_recognition_knn.py to do face recognition in python using KNN algorithm. When I read the code I found this

```
    # Find encodings for faces in the test iamge
    faces_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(X_img, known_face_locations=X_face_locations)

    # Use the KNN model to find the best matches for the test face
    closest_distances = knn_clf.kneighbors(faces_encodings, n_neighbors=1)

    are_matches = [closest_distances[0][i][0] <= distance_threshold for i in range(len(X_face_locations))]

    # Predict classes and remove classifications that aren't within the threshold
    return [(pred, loc) if rec else ("unknown", loc) for pred, loc, rec in zip(knn_clf.predict(faces_encodings), X_face_locations, are_matches)]
```

from the code above, is there a way to get a percentage of matching image... for example: I would like to know the percentage of image X when it compares to images that have been training

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at this one:
[%%% at github](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/wiki/Calculating-Accuracy-as-a-Percentage)
Adam Geitgey explaines that there is no direct way to convert distance to percentage ... but "something like that" is.

Comment: Hi @Bohdan,I have been take a look to that site and the thing that makes me confuse is how to get ```face_distance``` value. Is ```face_distance``` value comes from ```closest_distances``` (from above code that I have mentioned in my question) ?

Comment: Yes, it is, your closest_distances is the list of such distances... However, that distance between two faces is normalized by 1: when it is 0 - faces are exactly the same(100% similarity), and 1 means that they are absolutely different(0% similarity), right? So, my proposal is to use the simpliest percentage calculstion ` percent = (1.0 - distance) * 100.0 `  .  Nobody can see and understand the difference between 86% and 92%  image similarity, so why do you need to break your brain with that?!